# if range has values then insert them into another range Sql query

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a table with 4 columns readdate, tagname, value and amendedvalue in MSSQL 2008.  The first 3 are inserted by an sql job running at 8am in the morning and contain data ranging from 7am the previous day to 7am the current day in hourly averages.  The amended value can be changed via a web application by the user.

I want to be able to look at the previous days data and if there is a value in the amendedvalue column then update the same range the next day.  It will always be for the same range ie if the amended value is changed for tagname1 for the previous 24 hours then the next day will need to show the same value in the amendedvalue column for that 24 hour period.

Here is the code I use to select the previous days period

```
SELECT coalesce(amendedValue, value),
       readDate,
       tagName,
       amendedValue,
       value
FROM gasdata
WHERE tagname ='35FI8316'
  AND readDate 
    BETWEEN DateAdd(Hour, 7, DateAdd(DAY, DateDiff(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), -1)) 
    AND dateadd(hour, 6, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
ORDER BY readDate
```

Im just not sure how to get started, I believe it should be something like this

If amendedvalue has a value during this time period then update the amended value in the following period.

Bit complicated hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You could declare an `AmendedValue` variable and assign it to the last days data.

Then you would only update the table if the `AmendedValue` is equal to `1 or your custom value`

```
DECLARE @AmendedValue INT

SELECT @AmendedValue = amendedValue
FROM gasdata
Where tagname ='35FI8316' and readDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()

IF @AmendedValue = 1
BEGIN
   -- Update the table
END
```

Comment: will that just look for the value of 1?

Comment: @user2050577 - yes but you can change this to whatever value you require.

Comment: I would have to set it to is not null

Comment: @user2050577 you can set it to anything, you could also add WHERE amendedValue IS NOT NULL in your query.

Comment: The above code works, thanks darrren.  However how do I get it to copy each value from the first range and place it exactly into the second range?

Comment: `declare @amendedvalue int

SELECT @AmendedValue = amendedValue
FROM gasdata
Where tagname ='35FI8316' and readDate BETWEEN DateAdd(Hour, 7, DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GETDATE()), -2)) 
and dateadd(hour, 6, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))

IF @AmendedValue is not null
BEGIN
  update gasdata set amendedValue = ????  where tagname ='35FI8316' and readDate BETWEEN DateAdd(Hour, 7, DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GETDATE()), -1)) 
and dateadd(hour, 6, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
END`